# Is it possible to create same browser multi user login with Auth?

Tags: php, laravel

I have created one laravel project which is having front-end and back-end both.So i want to allow user to login in both panel at same time and with same browser.

I try this with multi-guard but it logs out another user when one user is login.

Comment: set middleware authentication in route

Comment: @RakibulIslam i have added middleware but it logs me out when i login with another user details,because auth set one session at a time as per my information.

Comment: Are you calling the "front-end" like a member login and the "back-end" like an Admin? If so you can distinguish the two as in a user/member or admin in your sessions. This also allows to program things so you to log in as a member from the admin area.